# Python Flask-admin et API REST

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

I'm coming to you because I have a little problem, indeed, I set up an admin menu with Flask-admin, which works very well.

The problem is that to interact with the postgresq database, I have to use the db.session as above

```
admin = Admin(app, name="My Project")
admin.add_view(adminModel.MyModelView(models.MyModel, db.session, "My text"))
```

But my interactions with the database are done via a REST API which is called in HTTP, so I would like to know how to link Flask-admin with my REST API and not with db.session ,

Comment: Do you not have a database object initialized within your application with access to your model?

I think I get what you're asking but some clarity about how your application is configured is necessary.

Comment: A REST API is not equivalent to a database, and nor is it a supplement for a database session

Answer (score 0):

Here is a data base model,

```
class Feasibility(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "feasibility"

    def get_id(self):
        return (self.id_feasibility)

    id_feasibility = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    UUID = db.Column(UUID(as_uuuid=True), default=uuuid.uuid4, unique=True, null=False)
    date_request = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True)
    datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow, null=False)
    description_feasibility = db.Column(db.String(1000), index=True)
    accepted = db.Column(db.Boolean, index=True, default=False)
    number_feasibility = db.Column(db.String(255), index=True)
```

the problem is that the production application must not have a direct connection to the database but must go through an API, but I can't configure Flask-admin to inject a connection to the API! finally I would like to replace that.

```
admin = Admin(app, name="My Project")

admin.add_view(adminModel.MyModelView(models.MyModel, db.session, "My text"))
```

By this

```
`admin = Admin(app, name="My Project")`


`admin.add_view(adminModel.MyModelView(models.MyModel, **API_URL**, "My text"))`
```

in advance thank you for your help